Assigning resources to stations and tasks
I am new to operational research and using Gurobi for the following:
I am trying to create a task allocation problem. There are 4 types of resources Skilled and Unskilled workers and Normal and Special Robots. Each of these resources can perform a task i and their timings are known. There are location j available. A skilled or special robot can perform more than one task at a time while an unskilled or normal worker can only perform one task at a time. If two tasks are now performed by a skilled worker/special robot then the next location can be merged into one. Picture as example:



I have added in the following decision Variables as X1,X2,R1,R2 for skilled/unskilled worker, normal/special robot respectively.
X1 is one if task i is assigned it unskilled worker at location j
The order of task is also known and is as follow:

The goal is to reduce total cycle time. I have been able to allocate tasks to a mix of resources based on lowest cycle time but I am having trouble allocating more than one task to the same resource and the merging of the stations. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Code as below:
# Decision Variables (NT no. of taks, NL no. of locations, NH1 no of unskilled workers, NH2 no. of skilled workers, NR1 no of normal robots, NR2 no of special robots.

X1={}
for i in NT:
for j in NL: 
    for h1 in NH1:
        X1[i,j,h1] = NC.addVar(vtype="B",name=f"X1({i},{j},{h1})")
X2={}
for i in NT:
for j in NL: 
    for h2 in NH2:
        X2[i,j,h2] = NC.addVar(vtype="B",name=f"X2({i},{j},{h2})") 
Y1={}
for i in NT:
for j in NL:
for r1 in NH1:
        Y1[i,j,r1] = NC.addVar(vtype="B",name=f"Y1({i},{j}),{r1}")

Y2={}
for i in NT:
for j in NL:
    for r2 in NH1:
        Y2[i,j,r2] = NC.addVar(vtype="B",name=f"Y2({i},{j}),{r2}")

#For H1 and R1 only one task to be assigned
for i in NT:
NC.addConstr(quicksum(Y1[i,j, r1] for j in NL for r1 in NR1) + quicksum(X1[i,j, h1] for j in NL for h1 in NH1) == 1)

#For R2 and H2 more than one task can be assigned
for i in NT:
NC.addConstr(quicksum(Y2[i,j, r2] for j in NL for r2 in NR2) + quicksum(X2[i,j, h2] for j in NL for h2 in NH2)>=1)

#precedence of tasks to be set for X2 and Y2 as they can handle more than one task
for i in NT:
for i1 in NT:
    if (i1!=i):
        NC.addConstr(quicksum(j*Y2[i,k,r2] for k in NL for r2 in NR2)<=quicksum(j*Y2[i1,k,r2] for k in NL for r2 in NR2))


for i in NT:
for i1 in NT:
    if (i1!=i):
        NC.addConstr(quicksum(j*X2[i,k,h2] for k in NL for h2 in NH2)<=quicksum(j*X2[i1,k,h2] for k in NL for h2 in NH2))

#Minimize total cycle time: 
NC.setObjective(quicksum(Tir1[i,j]*Y1[i,j,r1] for i in NT for j in NL for r1 in NR1) + quicksum(Tir2[i,j]*Y2[i,j,r2] for i in NT for j in NL for r2 in NR2)+ quicksum(Tih1[i,j]*X1[i,j,h1] for i in NT for j in NL for h1 in NH1) + quicksum(Tih2[i,j]*X2[i,j,h2] for i in NT for j in NL for h2 in NH2), GRB.MINIMIZE)


Welcome to OR.SE. It sounds like being a production line balancing problem rather than being a job-shop problem. Also, is it possible to elaborate more on the problem spec? E.g. by clarifying the processing time of each task, improving the attached pictures and the goal of those, and etc.

Hi Yes absolutely. Time taken for each task by each resource is in a 2D matrix. For example all normal robots available are under NR1. And time taken for each task is stored in the matrix Tir1. Similarly for Tir2, Tih1, Tih2 for special robots, normal workers and skilled workers respectively. @A.Omidi.
For the pictures we started with normal workers on all stations. Assumption is that skilled workers and special robots can handle more than tasks and is faster in handling those tasks as compared to unskilled workers. So they would replace the normal workers

sorry for my lateness. I strongly recommend you to take a look at these posts as good starting points. 1, 2, 3, 4.

@A.Omidi just wanted to say thank you! I've cracked the code
